# How to add an image to the vue project in different ways?

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, path, vuex

I'm expecting to add in image. But none of the ways works.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-fsg2l2?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHeader.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <a href="#" class="header__top-item facebook" :style="image"></a>
    <img alt="" src="../assets/icons/facebook-header.svg" />
    <img v-bind:src="require('../assets/icons/facebook-header.svg')" />
  </div>
</template>
     data() {
        return {
          image: { backgroundImage: 'url(../assets/icons/facebook-header.svg)' },
        };
      },
      
      // package.lson
      
      "dependencies": {
        "vue": "^3.2.26",
        "vue-loader": "^17.1.1",
        "vue-svg-loader": "^0.16.0",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.0.0",
        "webpack": "^5.0.0"
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

vue-svg-loader is not compatible with vue 3. To import svg and use it as a component, simply wrap the contents of the file in 'template'

Comment: But it was already nested inside template tag, please see the edited code.